# Unable to locate cause of memory leak in Android app

Tags: c#, android, memory, xamarin, memory-leaks

I built out this whole app thinking that the garbage collector handled memory clean-up just fine, which was incredibly stupid and naive of me, but hey, it was my first time every using Xamarin to build an app, and my first time ever building an app, so what's a guy to do? Every screen seems to leak memory, but the screens that leak the most are screens that have bitmaps, generating a memory dump and analyzing it in MAT, I found the following:

[image]

So there are 4 potential culprits, 2 are bitmaps, 2 are byte arrays. This is a heap dump for the main menu of the app, if I go into my list view activity for listing out elements, I get 5 potential leaks from bitmaps. Here is the code for the activity:

```
            AssetManager assets = Assets;

        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

        var topPanel = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.topPanel);
        topPanel.Text = service.GetLanguageValue("use recommendations - top bar heading");
        topPanel.Dispose();

        var lowerPanel = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.recommendationsPanel);
        lowerPanel.Text = service.GetLanguageValue("title upper - recommendations by variety");
        Shared.ScaleTextToOneLine(lowerPanel, lowerPanel.Text, Shared.ScaleFloatToDensityPixels(Shared.GetViewportWidthInDp()), 1.0f);
        lowerPanel.Dispose();

        // Read html file and replace it's contents with apple data
        string html = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("apple-variety-detail.html")))
        {
            html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        html = ReplaceAppleDetailsHtml(html);
        var webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.recommendationsMessage);
        CleanWebView();
        webview.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
        html,
        "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        if (Shared.currentApple != null)
        {
            // Setup apple image
            using (var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.recommendationsImage))
            {
                var apple = this.apples.Where(a => a.Id == Shared.currentApple.AppleId).Select(a => a).First();
                var imgName = apple.Identifier.First().ToString().ToUpper() + apple.Identifier.Substring(1);
                var fullImageName = "SF_" + imgName;

                using (var bitmap = Shared.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(ApplicationContext.Resources,
                                          Resources.GetIdentifier(fullImageName.ToLower(), "drawable", PackageName),
                                          200, 200))
                {
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }

            // Setup apple name
            FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.appleNameTextView).Text = Shared.currentApple.Name;

        }
        else
        {
            FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.appleNameTextView).Text = "Not Found!";
        }




        // Setup list menu for apples
        AppleListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ApplesListMenu);
        // Scale details and list to fit on the same screen if the screen size permits
        if (Shared.GetViewportWidthInDp() >= Shared.minPhoneLandscapeWidth)
        {
            var listViewParams = AppleListView.LayoutParameters;
            // Scales list view to a set width
            listViewParams.Width = Shared.ScaleFloatToDensityPixels(240);
            listViewParams.Height = Shared.ScaleFloatToDensityPixels(Shared.GetViewportHeightInDp());
            AppleListView.LayoutParameters = listViewParams;
        }
        else
        {
            // Here, we either need to hide the list view if an apple was selected, 
            // or set it to be 100% of the screen if it wasn't selected.
            if(!Shared.appleSelected)
            {
                var listViewParams = AppleListView.LayoutParameters;
                // Scales list view to a set width
                listViewParams.Width = Shared.ScaleFloatToDensityPixels(Shared.GetViewportWidthInDp());
                listViewParams.Height = Shared.ScaleFloatToDensityPixels(Shared.GetViewportHeightInDp());
                AppleListView.LayoutParameters = listViewParams;
            }
            else
            {
                var listViewParams = AppleListView.LayoutParameters;
                // Scales list view to a set width
                listViewParams.Width = Shared.ScaleFloatToDensityPixels(0);
                listViewParams.Height = Shared.ScaleFloatToDensityPixels(Shared.GetViewportHeightInDp());
                AppleListView.LayoutParameters = listViewParams;
            }
        }

        // Set listview adapter
        if(AppleListView.Adapter == null)
        {
            AppleListView.Adapter = new Adapters.AppleListAdapter(this, (List<Apple>)apples, this);
        }
        AppleListView.FastScrollEnabled = true;

        // Set the currently active view for the slide menu
        var frag = (SlideMenuFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<SlideMenuFragment>(Resource.Id.SlideMenuFragment);
        frag.SetSelectedLink(FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.SlideMenuRecommendations));

        // Replace fonts for entire view
        Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(assets, "fonts/MuseoSansRounded-300.otf");
        FontCrawler fc = new FontCrawler(tf);
        fc.replaceFonts((ViewGroup)this.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.recommendationsRootLayout));
        tf.Dispose();
    }
```

The important part to note about this is the way this activity works is it loads an adapter, and when it displays it shows a list of items, when an item is clicked, it reloads this same activity, and it computes the screen size, shrinks down the list to show only the webview off to the side, and displays details about the item, thus simulating 2 screens, the reason I did this is because when the screen size is larger, it needs to show all of this as one single view, so on larger screens it will actually show both the listview and the webview, but still reload the activity to load new data.

The adapter code is probably what is giving me a hard time, but I'm not sure, I've tried quite a few things, but nothing seems to help, here's the adapter code:

```
    public class AppleListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Apple>
{

    List<Apple> items;
    Activity context;
    ApplicationService service = AgroFreshApp.Current.ApplicationService;
    private Context appContext;
    private Typeface tf;
    static AppleRowViewHolder holder = null;

    public AppleListAdapter(Activity context, List<Apple> items, Context appContext): base ()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.appContext = appContext;
        context.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ApplesListMenu).ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
        tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "fonts/MuseoSansRounded-300.otf");
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Apple this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return items.Count;
        }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        var item = items[position];

        var view = convertView;

        var imgName = item.Identifier.First().ToString().ToUpper() + item.Identifier.Substring(1);
        var fullImageName = "SF_" + imgName;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.appleRowView, null);
        }

        if (view != null)
        {
            holder = view.Tag as AppleRowViewHolder;
        }

        if(holder == null)
        {
            holder = new AppleRowViewHolder();
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.appleRowView, null);
            holder.AppleImage = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iconImageView);
            holder.AppleName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameTextView);
            view.Tag = holder;
        }

        using (var bitmap = Shared.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(context.Resources,
                                    context.Resources.GetIdentifier(fullImageName.ToLower(), "drawable", context.PackageName),
                                    25, 25))
        {
            holder.AppleImage.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        holder.AppleName.Text = AgroFreshApp.Current.AppleDetailManager.GetAll().Where(a => a.AppleId == item.Id).Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        holder.AppleName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);

        view.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var apple = AgroFreshApp.Current.AppleManager.Get(item.Id);
            Shared.currentApple = AgroFreshApp.Current.AppleDetailManager.GetAll().Where(a=>a.AppleId == item.Id && a.LanguageId == service.UserSettings.LanguageId).Select(a=>a).FirstOrDefault();
            Shared.appleSelected = true;

            Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, typeof(RecommendationsActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(flags: ActivityFlags.NoHistory | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            appContext.StartActivity(intent);
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

So I'm using the viewholder pattern here, and assigning click events to each list item as they get generated, with nohistory and newtask as the intent flags so that the pages refreshes properly. To clean up the bitmaps, I have been using these two methods:

This cleans the large image on the details webview:

```
        public void CleanBitmap()
    {
        // Clean recommendations bitmap
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.recommendationsImage);
        Drawable drawable = imageView.Drawable;
        if (drawable is BitmapDrawable)
        {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)drawable;
            if (bitmapDrawable.Bitmap != null)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;
                if (!bitmap.IsRecycled)
                {
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
                    bitmap.Recycle();
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            }

        }

        Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Gc();
    }
```

And this cleans the bitmaps stored in each listview item:

```
        public void CleanListViewBitmaps()
    {
        var parent = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ApplesListMenu);

        // Clean listview bitmaps
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var tempView = parent.GetChildAt(i);
            // If the tag is null, this no longer holds a reference to the view, so 
            // just leave it.
            if(tempView.Tag != null)
            {
                AppleRowViewHolder tempHolder = (AppleRowViewHolder)tempView.Tag;

                var imageView = tempHolder.AppleImage;
                var drawable = imageView.Drawable;

                if (drawable is BitmapDrawable)
                {

                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)drawable;
                    if (bitmapDrawable.Bitmap != null)
                    {
                        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;
                        if (!bitmap.IsRecycled)
                        {
                            imageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
                            bitmap.Recycle();
                            bitmap = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Gc();
    }
```

They then get called in the activities ondestroy method like so:

```
        protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        CleanBitmap();
        CleanListViewBitmaps();
        Shared.appleSelected = false;
    }
```

I'm also using a shared class with static variables to essentially track view states like if something was selected or no, but it only stores primitives, it doesn't store any view objects or anything like that, so I don't think that is the problem like I said it looks like bitmaps aren't getting cleaned correctly, and it seems to happen on every view, but this one in particular is bad.

I also on each view load 2 fragments, one is a slide menu fragment in a frame layout, and the other is a navbar fragment that just holds 2 bitmaps for a logo and menu handle, so those could be culprits too I suppose. Here's the navbar fragment:

```
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.navbar, container, false);

        var navLogo = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.navbarLogo);
        var menuHandle = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.menuHandle);
        var navSpacer = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.navSpacer);

        ((ImageButton)(menuHandle)).SetMaxWidth(Shared.GenerateProportionalWidth(.25f, 50));
        ((ImageButton)(menuHandle)).SetMaxHeight(Shared.GenerateProportionalHeight(.25f, 50));

        ((ImageButton)(menuHandle)).Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var slideMenu = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.SlideMenuFragment);

            if (slideMenu.IsHidden)
            {
                FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Show(slideMenu).Commit();
            }
            else if (!slideMenu.IsHidden)
            {
                FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Hide(slideMenu).Commit();
            }
        };

        var navLogoParams = navLogo.LayoutParameters;
        // Account for the padding offset of the handle to center logo truly in the center of the screen
        navLogoParams.Width = global::Android.Content.Res.Resources.System.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels - (((ImageButton)(menuHandle)).MaxWidth * 2);
        navLogoParams.Height = (Shared.GenerateProportionalHeight(.25f, 30));
        navLogo.LayoutParameters = navLogoParams;

        // Spacer puts the logo in the middle of the screen, by making it's size the same as the handle on the opposite side to force-center the logo
        ((Button)(navSpacer)).SetMaxWidth(Shared.GenerateProportionalWidth(.25f, 50));
        ((Button)(navSpacer)).SetMaxHeight(Shared.GenerateProportionalHeight(.25f, 50));

        return view;
    }
```

Does anyone see any obvious or stupid mistake that I'm making? I feel like it has to just be sheer inexperience that's causing me to miss something really obvious, or I'm doing something completely wrong, either way.

EDIT #1:

1 of the bitmaps leaking was the menu handle button in the navigation fragment, so that drops the leak down from 300kb to 200kb, but I still need to figure out how to clean it properly.

EDIT #2:

Here is my code that scales bitmaps down

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.InSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        int height = options.OutHeight;
        int width = options.OutWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
        {

            int halfHeight = height / 2;
            int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth)
            {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I've figured out the problem. Xamarin is a c# wrapper around native java, so at runtime there is the native Java runtime, and the mono runtime as well, so any object like a bitmap that you want to cleanup, you need to cleanup the native Java object, but you also need to clean up the c# handle to the native object, because what happens is the garbage collector goes to see if it should clean your resource, sees a handle associated with the resource, and moves on. My solution was to call the c# dispose after I cleaned up the native Java object, and then call both the c# and Java garbage collector, I'm not sure if calling both garbage collectors is explicitly needed, but I chose to do it anyway. Seriously hope this helps someone out, I do not envy people who have to hunt down these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Bitmaps ar not garbage collected correctly, and generete the outofmemory exception.

my suggestion if you're working with bitmaps is to call 
`System.gc();`
to recycle bitmaps from memory correctly

Comment: The problem is that the imageviews are garbage collector roots, so they won't actually get garbage collected because something is referencing them, my method of cleaning bitmaps works as shown above by explicitly nulling them and recycling them, but then I can't reuse the bitmaps, because they've been recycled.

Comment: The other option to avoid it from generating the leak is to do the  image loading on background, this means you have to create an async task that on background gets the image bitmap process it and on post execute updates the view  you can red here what you can do in background to make it efficient https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Just realized, I'm already doing this, doesn't fix the leak, it just shrinks the amount of memory that leaks :/

Comment: can you share the asynctask to load images?, maybe there. is the leak happening